# Composition difference between #2 and #2D fuel oil

Tags: fuel

I have read that #2 and #2D fuel oil are essentially the same, but the #2D might have less sulfur. I have read others that say that #2 has a higher cloud point, so if that is true, then there are some differences.

I tried burning #2D in my furnace and it generated a noticeable oil fume in the house compared to #2 which generates no fumes. Why would #2D be generating oily fumes if it is cleaner?

Comment: For the US (your mileage may vary), ASTM defines three grades, 2S15, 2S500, and 2S5000. There is no 2D defined by ASTM standards.

Comment: ? See: [Diesel Fuel Grades](https://www.dieselnet.com/standards/us/fuel.php)